# SSIS For Loop does not break out of loop

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package where I am trying to use a For Loop to check a condition (web service response). I have a condition in the EvalExpression within SSIS and I am setting one of the variables in that EvalExpression within a dataflow task that is inside the loop. I am also logging the expression as well as the variables in the expression, and when the EvalExpression should turn false, the loop keeps going. Can someone please explain why that is? Or how can I get the true EvalExpression each iteration.

This is my EvalExpression

```
(@[User::statusMessageLoop] == 1 && @[User::statusMessageLoopCheck] == 1)
```

The variable User::statusMessageLoopCheck is set at each iteration of the loop and when I want it to break out of the loop, I set it to 0.

I hope the images below help explain my situation, and thank you all for your input.

[for loop properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGVlZ.jpg)

[conditions under where i want the loop to keep going](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALoBS.jpg)

[break out of the loop when these condition are true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PcRZ.jpg)

Comment: How are you setting your loop check variable?

Comment: @KeithL - In my data flow task that's inside the For Loop, I am using a derived column where I read the XML web service response and set a variable called statusMessageIndicator to either a 1 or 0 depending on the status message from the web service. After that step, I am using a zappysys package (Set Variable Transform, https://zappysys.com/onlinehelp/ssis-powerpack/ > Transforms > Set Variable Transform) to set the LoopCheck variable to whatever the statusMessageIndicator brings back. I also understand this is extra code that is not needed, but I was trying different things so I left it. thx

Comment: I use ZappySys as well but haven't used that object. Let me give you an answer on how to use a script task for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are reading your XML into columns properly and you know how to do that.

1. Add a script component and select "Transformation"
2. Add your variable (I am calling mine isTrue) as read-write
3. Select your column as read on inputs
4. Enter the script
5. Add the following code to set your variable

   ```
   Variables.isTrue = Row.isTrue == true ? 1 : 0;
   ```

This is basic if then else logic.

This is how you set a variable using SSIS inherit tools.

If this isn't working, maybe you should check to make sure you are reading the XML properly.

EDIT:

You need an interim variable to hold the test result and then you can set the Package Variable in the post execute. Here is a screen shot of the code:

[image]

Sorry about this. I learned this lesson with you. I typically handle all XML and JSON entirely inside C#.

Note that bool test is declared outside of row processing as well.

This assumes you only have one row of processing as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not having much luck with this, but it could also be because of I am doing this.

When I extract the XML column that I am checking status again, I add the output of that to the Script Component. In the script component, under Script tab, I set the ReadWriteVariables to include the isTrue int variable that I created. In input columns I select the API response variable from XML. In Edit Script under the Input0_ProcessInputRow class I have (1 of 2)

Comment: (2 of 3)
Variables.isTrue = Row.OracleResponse == "succeeded" || Row.OracleResponse == "ERROR" || Row.OracleResponse == "WARNING" ? 1 : 0;

when I save and run the process, I get the below error message:
Error: 0xC0047062 at Get ESS Job Status For Loop (API), Script Component [136]: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ReadWriteVariablesNotAvailableException: The collection of variables locked for read and write access is not available outside of PostExecute.

Comment: (3 of 3) @KeithL
Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Script Component" (136) failed with error code 0x80131600 while processing input "Input 0" (146). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Can you add a pic of your data flow?

Comment: See below... hopefully these will work.
![For Loop](https://imgur.com/AJ5TYl9)
![Data Flow](https://imgur.com/YSRXElH)
![Transformation - Script](https://imgur.com/0HY7sTL)
![Transformation - Input Columns](https://imgur.com/kmtmgVd)
![Transformation - Input and Outputs](https://imgur.com/zsG1rTp)
![Transformation - Edit Script](https://imgur.com/V9vAEJT)

Comment: the error message above relates to setting a variable in the Row level processing. The variable has to be set in post execute. I will add some images.

Comment: @BMatic Updated answer

Comment: thank you for that. My C# code is working, but my loop is still not breaking. Would you mind to post a screenshot of what the For Loop expressions should be?

Also, thank you for working through this with me. It has been a great help.

Comment: See images as well of my current loop expression  
  
[loop expression](https://imgur.com/7xjGFr6)  
[status check](https://imgur.com/YLzXu7S)  
  
I get stuck in an infinite loop with these conditions.

Comment: Keith were you able to look at my updated comments? @KeithL